# Using extended class in static Method

Tags: php, static-methods

New to OOP.
Is there Any work around for Using extended class instance in static method.
Suppose I have a complete class for databases.

```
class Mysql{

     public function getrecords(){

      } 

}

Class login extends Mysql{

     public static method(){

      $this->getrecords()

                           }

}
```

Now using Like:

```
login::method();
```

Although code written above is not valid, but how can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2286720/921154

Comment: Don't combine static methods with instance methods - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Static methods have very limited use, use them only for very specific purposes. See [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: You're new and you're already looking for workarounds?  This suggests you are doing something fundamentally wrong.  Like trying to use `$this` in a static context.

Comment: Also the syntax is `class Foo { ... }` there is no parentheses `()` after the class name.

Comment: `Class login extends Mysql` - ask yourself: is the following statement true? "a login is a MySQL"? If not, your class design is just wrong.

Comment: leftclickben; sorry for syntax. Means there is no way to achieve that. can i get method instantiated in Mysql in static method and then use in login class?

Comment: fab; it's just put a case to see if this can be done or not? may be i should think some other way

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `self::` instead of `$this->`, but it only makes sense if **both methods** are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve this functionality

class Mysql{

```
 public function getrecords(){
        echo "test";
  }
```

}

class Login extends Mysql{

```
 public static function method(){
        parent::getrecords();
}
```

}
Login::method();

Comment: So could you elaborate the functionality you want?