# Using $this when not in object context model class

Tags: php, class, protected

I have stated my bespoke MV, I have a simple Model + controller classes and I can't get the var in the model to be recognsed when called by a different function

The controller class is

```
  class StaffController {

    protected $module = "staff";

    public function __construct()
    {
        //include the staff Model
        require_once(MODEL_PATH.$this->module.'.php');
    }
    public function index() {

        // we store all the posts in a variable
        $staff = Staff::all();

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($staff);

    }
```

And  `$staff = Staff::all();` calls the model class, and its the  `$list` variable that isn't recognized:

```
  class Staff {

    public $list = array();

    public function __construct() {
          $this->list = [];
    }


    public static function all() {
      //get all the staff 

      $temp = [];

      $db = Db::getInstance();

      $req = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY ParentID ASC');

      // we create a list of Post objects from the database results
      foreach($req->fetchAll() as $staff) { array_push($temp,$staff);

      self::reorderOrg($temp );

      return $final;
    }


    private static function reorderOrg($array, $parent = 0, $depth = 0){
          //reorganise org 

        for($i=0, $ni=count($array); $i < $ni; $i++){
            //check if parent ID same as ID

            if($array[$i]['parentID'] == $parent){

                array_push($this->list ,$array[$i]); //***** no being recognized

                self::reorderOrg($array, $array[$i]['id'], $depth+1);

            }
        }

        return true;
      }


  }
```

I get the following error  **Using $this when not in object context** in and its to do with the array_push in the model class not liking `$this->list`. How do a set the private var so it can be used within its own class funcitons

Comment: You don't have a "this" context in a static method. You'd have to call `self::$list` instead of `$this->list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` keyword means that that function is called on the class itself, not on an instance of the class. That means `$this` doesn't refer to anything.

If it's a function that needs to be called on a specific instance so that you have access to its members, you'll need to either make it non-static or pass in an instance of the class (probably the former, since that's what a non-static method is for).

As far as having the class keep a list of its instances: What you're doing here is initializing a `list` on an *instance* of your class, so each instance will have an empty list. This may not be what you're intending.

Answer (score 0):

you are not in *object context* because your function is *static*. you have to use `self` instead. `self` refers to the current class:

```
array_push(self::list, $array[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple cannot use `$this` in static methods because static methods are not part of the instantiated object to which `$this` refers. Static methods can be called even if the object is not instantiated.

You have to make `reorderOrg` non-static in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about static methods and properties in PHP.

You can not access `$this` in static method because you do not have any instance of the class which should be referred as `$this`.

You have two options here

1. Declare property as static and access it with `self` keyword. For example

   // Declaration

   public static $list = array();

   // Access

   self::$list[] = 'something';
2. Create an object of the class and access property of the created object.

   // Create object

   $staff = new Staff();

   // Access

   $staff->list[] = 'something';

Remember to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)!

Answer (score 0):

Related Post: [Using this inside a static function fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286696/using-this-inside-a-static-function-fails)

Does this answer your issue? When using a static method; you must use self:: not $this->

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

```
array_push(self::list,...);
```