# error using $this in non-object context.intelephense(1030) and Non-static method cannot be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class with the structure below. And Im trying to call a method of the class with "$this->getTopProds($prodsInfo)" however Im getting an error:

```
 "Cannot use '$this' in non-object context.intelephense(1030)"
```

And on the page the error is "Non-static method App\JsonResponse\Prod\ProdRender:: getTopProds() cannot be called statically".

Do you know what can be the issue?

```
class ProdRender
{
    public static function hotel(array $prodsInfo): array
    {

        dd($this->getTopProds($prodsInfo));

    }

   

    private function getTopProds(array $prodsInfo)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using $this inside a static function fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286696/using-this-inside-a-static-function-fails)

Comment: You can't use `$this` inside a static function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286714/1418750

Comment: But so do you know how to call the class method inside the class? Using self it shows "Call to undefined method App\JsonResponse\Prod\ProdRender::classgetTopProds()

".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't use `this` keyword inside a `static` method. “this” refers to the current instance of the class. But if we define a method as static, the class instance will not have access to it

To keep using the other method call inside the static method  you need to change the second method `getTopProds` to be static too, and call it with `self`
`self::getTopProds($prodsInfo)`

Comment: Thanks, so in this case do you know how to call the method?

Comment: you need to either change the first method to be a non static method & keep the other as you did 
or change the second method to be static too and call it with `self` key 
`self::getTopProds($prodsInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

In case you need it try this:

```
<?php
class ProdRender
{
    public function hotel(array $prodsInfo)
    {

        return $this->getTopProds($prodsInfo);

    }
    
    private function getTopProds(array $prodsInfo)
    {
        return $prodsInfo;
    }
}

$ho = new ProdRender();
$response = $ho->hotel(["fadf","ceec"]);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).