# How to hide some fields through a trait in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to force some fields to be hidden through a trait; I have implemented the below code but it didn't work.

```php
trait HideSensitiveData {

    protected static function booted() {

        $self = new self();
        $self->hidden = [
            'deleted_at',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'sort_index',
            'is_active',
        ];
    }

}
```

Also, I tried to implement it inside the trait constructor, but it led to other issues that I didn't want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286720

Comment: That wasn't my answer